# Count groups of same characters in R

Tags: r, string, count, data.table

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
str <- "FRFFFLRR".
```

What is the best way to get this kind of data.table output out of my string:

```
x    y  
F    1  
R    1  
F    3  
L    1  
R    2
```

Notice that the 'F's and the 'R's does not count together unless they are next to each other.
So, I need a way to count groups of the same characters. Do you have an idea?

I already tried to split the individual letters, and then used `unique()`, but this left me with the problem that an additional group of a previously occurred letter got neglected. In this case, it gave me "F R L" instead of "F R F L R".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split at every character and use `rleid` to divide data into groups based on consecutive values and count number of rows in each group.

```
library(data.table)

x <- strsplit(str, '')[[1]]
data.table(x)[, .(x = first(x), y = .N), rleid(x)]

#   rleid x y
#1:     1 F 1
#2:     2 R 1
#3:     3 F 3
#4:     4 L 1
#5:     5 R 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rle` from `base R` after doing the `strsplit`

```
do.call(data.frame, rle(strsplit(str, "")[[1]]))[2:1]
#    values lengths
#1      F       1
#2      R       1
#3      F       3
#4      L       1
#5      R       2
```